# smackx cannot login to ejabberd socketexception sent failed pipe broken

Tags: android, authentication, ejabberd

I am developing a chat function in my app. Using the code below I was able to connect to openfire and smackx to connect and login. everything was working fine. Unfortunately, openfire does not have acknowledgment xep in it yet. I wanted to use mod_stanza_ack by mingism for this purpose. Unfortunately, ejabberd2.1.11 cannot login with the error below in logcat.
I have tried all variations to login but I get the same error or it just doesn't login but it can connect to server. This definitely is not due to switch of wifi and gsm. Could anyone please help out?

Code for connecting and logging in :

```
public void init() throws XMPPException {

// for connecting to ejabberd2 and logging in. could connect but cannot login

ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(ip_address, 5222,     
ProxyInfo.forDefaultProxy());

//for connecting to openfire and logging in. works fine.
//ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(ip_address);

//connConfig.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
connConfig.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);
connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

   // Connect to server
   try {
       connection.connect();

                   System.out.println("Connected to " + 
   connection.getHost());   
    }
       catch (XMPPException ex) {

               System.out.println("Failed to connect " + 
   connection.getHost()); 
         }

   }

public void performLogin(String username, String password) throws     
XMPPException {

if(connection!=null && connection.isConnected()){

        // Login to server
        System.out.println("Logging in...");  
        try {
        connection.login(username, password);
        System.out.println("Logged in as " + connection.getUser());

        // packet listener: listen for incoming messages of type CHAT on the connection (whatever the buddy) 
        PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat); 

        connection.addPacketListener( packetListener = new PacketListener() { 
        public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
```

Logcat:
03-24 22:52:27.771: W/System.err(31926): java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
03-24 22:52:27.781: W/System.err(31926):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:506)
03-24 22:52:27.781: W/System.err(31926):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:475)
03-24 22:52:27.781: W/System.err(31926):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:507)
03-24 22:52:27.781: W/System.err(31926):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
03-24 22:52:27.781: W/System.err(31926):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:269)
03-24 22:52:27.781: W/System.err(31926):    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBytes(OutputStreamWriter.java:167)
03-24 22:52:27.781: W/System.err(31926):    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:158)
03-24 22:52:27.781: W/System.err(31926):    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:124)
03-24 22:52:27.781: W/System.err(31926):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketWriter.writePackets(PacketWriter.java:168)
03-24 22:52:27.781: W/System.err(31926):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketWriter.access$000(PacketWriter.java:40)
03-24 22:52:27.781: W/System.err(31926):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketWriter$1.run(PacketWriter.java:69)
03-24 22:52:27.781: W/System.err(31926): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
03-24 22:52:27.791: W/System.err(31926):    at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
03-24 22:52:27.791: W/System.err(31926):    at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:151)
03-24 22:52:27.791: W/System.err(31926):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:177)
03-24 22:52:27.791: W/System.err(31926):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:473)
03-24 22:52:27.791: W/System.err(31926):    ... 9 more

Answer (score 1):

As Mickael said, the server is not accepting the connection. Check the ejabberd logs on why. The error shown means you are trying to write to the connection while the connection is disconnected ([Android : Socket - java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622700/android-socket-java-net-socketexception-sendto-failed-epipe-broken-pipe)).

Comment: Hello, I have tried everything but to no avail. Also ejabberd does not give any logs even. on all the systems I have tried (see my comment in the above answer)

Answer (score 0):

You should look in ejabberd logs. As you said you have added a custom module to ejabberd, my guess is that the code is not compliant and make ejabberd client session crash and disconnect the client as a result.

Comment: Actually I have installed ejabberd on three different operating systems, Windows, Ubuntu, and MacOS. only In windows I have added the new module. But this error is happening with all of them.

Comment: I have tried 2.1.11, 13.xx and 15.xx versions of ejabberd without any modules but all have same error. I am not sure why!

Comment: I could login with spark but not my own client. I still get the same error no matter what I do.

Comment: You need to add more logging in your client then, to find your mistake more easily.

Comment: I  have added all the possible exceptions to be displayed in logcat and all of them give a service not available 503 exception during login!